# Invalid code signature due to inadequate entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to run an app on my physical device, it starts to build onto my device then crashes due to an 'invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user.'

I have updated my iPhone and Xcode to the latest release, tried to clean the build and edit run scheme build configuration to 'Release' and tried to set my executable to 'Ask On Launch'. I searched for a Iphone Developer file on keychain and could not seem to find one but i am not sure what i am supposed to do.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The error, as it says; either proper provisioning profile and certificate are not used. Or you might want to goto Settings app, look for your app and then trust the certificate. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

The problem is that the developer is not trusted with the device. If you manually try to run the apps on the device, you will see an `Untrusted Developer message`.

To solve this issue on the device, go to `Settings > General > VPN and Device Management` in newer iOS versions and `Settings > General > Profiles` or `Settings > General > Device Management` in older iOS versions (depending on the device type and the iOS version).

There, trust the developer and allow the apps to run.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But i though had to consult the information in the following link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204460

Comment: 1. its outdated, its Settings > General > VPN and Devicemanagement now
2. I added my self signed cert to my iPhone (the one that has been created in Xcode for the project) und installed it, and it did show up there, but it says its not validated I there is no way to validate it my self.

Answer (score 47):

For newer versions on your iPhone (version 14+)

```
Settings > General > Device Management (In the VPN section past Date & Time section). 
Then trust the device
```

Adding newer settings
2022 iPhone 15 variation. Load the app --> Next as below.

```
Settings > General > 
VPN & Device Management > Developer App > Trust "Apple Development:....."
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped! I had to trust myself again on my iPhone :)

Comment: 2022 iPhone 15 variation. 

Load the app --> Next as below. 

Settings > General > VPN & Device Management >

Developer App >

Trust "Apple Development:....."

Answer (score 15):

Please check the internet connection of the Testing IOS device, Signature verification fails if device isn't connected to Internet.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, I just

1. Created a new Project with the sample *Hello world*
2. Deployed it to the device - it was working
3. Deployed my desired app again and it started working

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

In my case simply reconnecting the lightning cable did the job.

Comment: funny yeah it worked, but then the above procedures needed too.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing works, do this,

Open XCode -> Window -> Devices & Simulators.
Remove your device from that window.
Reconnect the device and you will receive the trust certificate again.

This work after upgrading to iOS 15.

Answer (score 1):

If you see this issue happen out of nowhere, one other possible source of the problem is a network outage.

Your device will periodically need to dial out to a service to validate the provisioning profile. I don't have details on how often this needs to happen but I do know this validation action happens during the app's startup. If your device can't connect to the internet or Apple is experiencing an outage, it can interrupt this process and produce this error.

You can check the status of Apple's services here:
https://developer.apple.com/system-status/
**Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles** is what you want to keep an eye on.

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode error:**

> Could not launch "<app_name>" 
> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to launch <bundle_identifier> because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user.

From iOS v15:

```
Settings -> General -> VPN & Device Management -> <developer_app_section> -> Trust/Verify App
```

Also, if it is a new device do not forget to enable developer mode.

Error:

> To use <iphone_name> for development, enable Developer Mode in Settings → Privacy & Security.

```
Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Developer Mode -> on
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above works and you've already trusted the developer, try 4G/5G connection instead of wifi.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue on my device, and in my case, it was due to improper date and time settings in the general settings. The solution is straightforward – make sure to set the correct date and time in the phone's general settings.

Here are the steps to resolve the issue:

Go to your phone's settings.
Navigate to the general settings.
Locate the date and time settings.
Ensure that the date and time are set accurately.
This should resolve the problem you're facing. If you have any further questions or encounter issues, feel free to ask for additional assistance.

Hope this helps!