# Verification error happened when deploying my app using xcode

Tags: xcode

I was trying to deploy my app on my own iPhone but my iPhone keeps giving me this error saying: An internet connection is required to verify trust of the developer "Apple Development:....." and Xcode shows the error saying: The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to launch com.TestApp because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user. But both my laptop and phone are connected to the internet.

so I googled and see if anyone has this issue, and I found:
[Invalid code signature due to inadequate entitlements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61865231/invalid-code-signature-due-to-inadequate-entitlements)

people in there said they just approved the app in the device management section which I have done. As you can see the picture below, I have been pressing the verify apps button, but nothing have been verified. Does anyone have any idea? thanks!
[image]

Comment: I got this issue also. But when my phone had an internet connection, it worked well.

Comment: Both my laptop and phone got internet as well but it just doesn’t work

Comment: Did any of you guys find a way to solve this? Same situtation here, I do have connection on both laptop and phone, yet the verify doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

n my case it was solved, because apparently it was the firewall that was blocking it, so I set it to 4g internet